# Result from two tables without join condition

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this

```
SELECT COUNT(u.user_id) AS count1 FROM users WHERE user_id>1001 
UNION
SELECT COUNT(c.hits) AS count2 FROM source c WHERE loginid LIKE 'fb%';
```

Result

```
count1 
250
56
```

How can it be  made  in a single row like this

```
count1   count2
250      56
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using a sub-query:

```
select 
      (SELECT COUNT(u.user_id) AS count1 from users where user_id>1001) as count1,
      (select count(c.hits) AS count2 from source  c where loginid like 'fb%') as count2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(count1) AS count1,
       SUM(count2) AS count2
FROM(
    SELECT COUNT(u.user_id) AS count1, 0 AS count2 from users where user_id>1001

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 0 AS count1, count(c.hits) AS count2 from source  c where loginid like 'fb%';
)a;
```

Comment: This wont work because the upper query will not find the count2 column in the inner query. Dumitrescu Bogdan has given the right answer

Comment: It will work as `UNION` needs same number of columns having same alias. why don't you try it? see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html